# Which part of the Java Language Specification describes the behaviour of omitted varargs?

Tags: java, variadic-functions, jls

I am looking for a relevant portion of the Java Language Specification (JLS) which describes the behaviour when invoking a variable arity (vararg) method.

Consider the method:

```
public static void printVarArgs(String... args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
}
```

If I invoke the method like so:

```
printVarArgs();
```

The output will look like: `[]` because the omission of `args` at the call site has been converted into an empty array in the `printVarArgs` method.

I am looking for the point of the JLS which defines this behaviour. The closest I have found is [15.12.4.2 Evaluate Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2), but it doesn't give this example, and I'm not sure if this case is actually covered by the formal/mathematical description.

Which part of the JLS describes the automatic creation of an empty array when a vararg is omitted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text of that JLS section says:

> If the method being invoked is a variable arity method (§8.4.1) `m`, it necessarily has `n > 0` formal parameters. The final formal parameter of `m` necessarily has type `T[]` for some `T`, and m is necessarily being invoked with `k >= 0` actual argument expressions.
>
> If m is being invoked with kn actual argument expressions, or, if m is being invoked with `k != n` actual argument expressions and the type of the kth argument expression is not assignment compatible with `T[]`, then the argument list `(e1, ... , en-1, en, ...ek)` is evaluated as if it were written as `(e1, ..., en-1, new T[]{en, ..., ek})`.

In the case you are talking about, there are `k == n - 1` formal arguments, so `en, ..., ek` is an empty sequence, and that means the argument is evaluated as if it was `(e1, ..., en-1, new T[]{})`.

In other words, the behaviour is specified in the section you were looking at.

Answer (score 5):

From JLS 15.12.4.2:

> The final formal parameter of m necessarily has type T[] for some T, and m is necessarily being invoked with k >= 0 actual argument expressions.

That's from the callee perspective. I'm not sure where it states from the caller's perspective the behavior you cite, but it's kind of implied.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I +1'd, but I accepted the other answer as I find it slightly more explanatory.